# Mouse only works when I drag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, mouse

I was on a "Geopolitical" Minecraft server until my mouse started dragging. I made a video to show [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWG2syKPuow&feature=youtu.be)

Also I have tried many solutions, fixing my drivers, turning off touchscreen mode, and turning off sticky keys.

I am on windows 10, I have a Trust GXT wireless gaming mouse, and a Lenovo laptop.

Comment: Wow, that's strange. I've never seen that bug. Which Lenovo laptop specifically are you using? Does the same issue happen in 1.14.4?

Comment: Have you actually disabled Minecraft's touchscreen mode, or just Windows'?

Comment: This looks more like a connection problem. Does this happen when you play on singleplayer?